# environment problem in yml file for docker

Tags: php, docker, environment

i make an error on the point   youmas:
environment:
XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1 remote_port=9000 remote_enable=1
networks:
- youmas

but i dont know how to fix them

```
version: "3"
services:
  #PHP
  youmas-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - WITH_XDEBUG=true
    image: youmas-app
    container_name: youmas-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS:
        dev
        # If you down want to use xDebug, set remote_enable=0
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.178.33 remote_port=9001
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/production/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

  youmas:
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1 remote_port=9000 remote_enable=1
    networks:
      - youmas

  #Nginx
  youmas-webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "./docker/production/nginx/Dockerfile"
    container_name: youmas-webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/production/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./docker/production/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./docker/production/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    networks:
      - youmas
    command: '/bin/sh -c ''while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g "daemon off;"'''

  # Certbot SSL
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./docker/production/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./docker/production/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"


  #MySQL
  youmas-database:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: youmas-database
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: youmas
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: K4@|ahdpof8@@!~
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./docker/production/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - youmas

  #PHP My Admin
  youmas-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    links:
      - youmas-database:youmas-database
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: codeverze
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: codeverze
    networks:
      - youmas

#Networks
networks:
  youmas:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

any solution?

Comment: Most visibly the `youmas:` container doesn't have either an `image:` or `build:` line, so there's not obviously a container to run.  What's the actual error message?  Can you [edit] the question to include only a [mcve], on the one hand making sure to include the error and on the other deleting all of the parts of the Compose file that aren't necessary to demonstrate it?

Answer (score 2):

Your Syntax is wrong,
Replace the environment section to look like this :

```yaml
youmas-app:
    build:
      context: .
...
...
...
    environment:
      - 'SERVICE_NAME=app'
      - 'SERVICE_TAGS=dev'
...
...
```